# JQUERY - Not reacting to event call when class added

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that is used to switch background images on different nav menus within a horizontal scrolling site.

The problem I hav is that once i've added the.swap class to a image dynamically it doesnt react to the click call?  Any ideas gratefully received!

Cheers
Paul

```
$('img.swap').click(function() {

var thisSrc = $('img.active').attr("src");
var alteredSrc = (thisSrc).slice(0, -7)+".png";
$('img.active').attr("src",alteredSrc);
$('img.active').addClass("swap");
$('ul.navigation li img').removeClass("active");
var thisSrc = $(this).attr("src");
initImg = $(this).attr("src");  
var imgType = (initImg).slice(-4);
var greyImg = initImg.slice(0, -4) + "_up" + imgType;
$(this).attr("src",greyImg);
$(this).addClass("active");
$(this).removeClass("swap");
 );
```

Comment: use jquery live , your code should work , live binds all future elements which are going to get added to DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function, which attaches an event handler to all the elements matching a selector, now and in the future.

Comment: Thats great cheers - I'm half way there - But.. the other half of my issue is that the following hover function also needs to be live, I've added the live code, but the hover out effect doesnt work?
    $('img.swap').live('hover', function() {
      
        
   initImg = $(this).attr("src"); 
   var imgType = (initImg).slice(-4);
   
  
   var greyImg = initImg.slice(0, -4) + "_up" + imgType;
   
   
   $(this).attr("src",greyImg);
   
    }, function() {
   $(this).attr("src",initImg);
   
  });

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jquery live

http://api.jquery.com/live/

as they are added dynamically

Comment: cheers, can you use live with mouse hovers aswell?  seems to work on mouse over but not out, as in above code

Comment: @Paul you can use latest hover function http://api.jquery.com/hover/ which handles both.